# Create Browser Environment in OPENAI UNIVERSE

Tags: openai-gym

How to create a new environment in OPEN AI Universe to use my Website to perform actions ?

I tried with the DUSK GAME. It works good.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer might be slightly outdated and the [universe repository](https://github.com/openai/universe#world_of_bits) is archived now, you can take a look at the ["Mini World of bits" benchmark](http://alpha.openai.com/miniwob/index.html) from OpenAI. They did setup a VNC client-remote connection to let an agent operate on websites. Additionally they also had experiments with live websites for e.g. booking flights etc.

Kind regards